# $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)g(x) = +\infty$. True or false?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> True or false? If true, justify. If false, give counter-example. If $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions such that $f$ is bounded and positive and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = +\infty$, so $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)g(x) = +\infty$.

According to the answer key (I took a look at it because I had no idea how to answer this), that statement is false. So, let $f(x)=\sin{x}+1$. What about $g(x)$? No function came to my mind yet to serve as a counter-example. Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried literally any $g(x)$ that tends to infinity? Consider the sequence $x_n = (\tfrac 32 + 2n)\pi$. What is the value of $f(x_n) g(x_n)$?

Comment: Do you mean positive or non-negative.  And must $f$ be continuous.  But you can have $f(x) = \frac 1{g(x)}$ on a regular basis and have it "overpower" the $g(x)$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, I tried $g(x)=x$, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, your $f(x)$ isn't strictly speaking positive but rather non-negative. This can be done taking a properly positive $f$. Try $f(x) = 1$ for $x < 0$, and $f(x) = 1/(1 + x)$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Setting $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$, and $f(x)=1/(1+x)$ for $x≥0$ and $g(x)=x$ work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: The function $1+\sin(x)$ is not strictly positive.  Try instead $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

Answer (score 3):

Counter example: $f(x)=e^{-x^2},g(x)=x^2.$

Comment: So  the heart of the issue is that you want $f$ positive such that $f \to 0$ "at least as fast as"  $g \to \infty$. So $f=|1/x|$ and $g=|x|$ is probably the simplest example. Then their product is 1.

Comment: But $f(x)$ isn't bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ . Though it can be easily corrected.

Comment: Right, just let $f(x)=\frac 1{1+x^2}.$

Comment: Or let $f(x) = 1$ for $x < 1$.  We are only concerned about the behavior at large values of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)$ be anything where where $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \infty$ (for example $g(x) = x$).  Let $f(x)$ be any function so that $f(x)$ is generally $\le  \frac 1{g(x)}$.  Okay we mus make some conditions so that $f$ is always bounded and positive, so for example $f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & g(x) < 1\\ \frac 1{g(x)}& g(x) \ge 1\end{cases}$.

The $f(x)$ is bounded ($ 0 < f(x) \le 1$)$ and so....

So $f(x)g(x)= \begin{cases} g(x) & g(x) < 1\\ 1 & g(x) \ge 1\end{cases}$

And $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)g(x) \ne \infty$.

In fact, I'll leave it to you to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1{g(x)}g(x) = 1$.  (Because there is an $M$ so that $g(x) > 1$ for all $x > M$).